# Queue length on review page does not reflect filters

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

Tag filters on the review page are really useful - makes sure you are only presented with for instance votes to re-open in areas you actually know something about.

The only problem is that the review front page (for want of a better name) may show that there are N posts in the queue for you to review, but when you go to the page, the message is that there are no posts for you to review. I presume because of the filters that I have set.

Would it be possible to see the number of posts for review corrected for the user's actual filters for each queue?

I realise that this is a user experience issue, and a luxury one at that - but then again, the review system is beginning to work nicely and one can begin to look at the details.

PS: A modification to this effect would also have the added benefit of playing down the 50k close vote queue, which continues to stare at me with an uncomfortable insistence.

Comment: It's not always because of the filters - it's also highly likely because of the high throughput of the review queues. Items disappear before you can even open it. The numbers on the review front page are cached for a number of minutes (5, I believe).

Comment: My previous comment aside - I like the idea of seeing a count respecting the current filters.

Comment: @J.Steen I realise that the throughput is impressive - but sometimes the number of posts in the queue is so big (>15, say) that it has to be an effect of the filters as well - and if there are 0 posts for you to review (filtered) then there is not even a reason to click on the link. One small UX nuisance with the review system removed.

Comment: It's still never going to be perfect due to the delay in update of information on the front page. That information is not live. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: I've seen it many times where the filters definitely play a part, as Monolo says, sometimes the number is too high for it just to be caching / throughput.

Comment: @J.Steen also - now that George Duckett has revived this remark of mine - I never asked for a perfect system. One that is "good enough" will do fine.