# "There are no items for you to review" when click on review

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits

After achieving 2k reputations on Askubuntu, I can Review on following post

- First Posts
- Low Quality Posts
- Suggested Edits
- Late Answers

I see **pop-up for pending review** as following:
[image]

But It says:-

> "There are no items for you to review, matching the filter
>   "[shortcuts]

---

**Also if I click on Suggested Edits on Review page as following, Then it says same:-**

[image]

---

So, Why it is not showing review for **suggested edits** & **what pop-up stands for then?**

Comment: And if you remove your filter? Notice that the indicator or the post count doesn't take your filter into account!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

5 low quality posts **in total**. Not within your tag. It does even say it to you:

> There are no items for you to review, matching the filter [shortcuts]

If there was shown following message

> There are no items for you to review.

Then there would be no posts to review **at all**.

So remove filter to see all invisible reviews.

Comment: There is a [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173008/queue-length-on-review-page-does-not-reflect-filters) to fix this.

Comment: @rene Good! :-) But this question is not a feature request.

Comment: It doesn't have many votes I really think: meah...

Comment: @rene Start a bounty ;-)

Comment: @nicael Yes, I clear filter and it now showing reviews. But it should not be  per-filtered.

Comment: @Pandya As rene mentioned, there is a [request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173008/queue-length-on-review-page-does-not-reflect-filters) to implement it. Vote it up (and maybe start a bounty)! :-) Maybe it will be completed in a few years :D

Comment: Features get normally implemented within 6-8 units...